# Automate Illustrator "Text Output Options" dialogue for batch exporting

Tags: scripting, autoit, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to batch export 100s of Adobe Illustrator files but after each file a "Text Export Options" dialogue box comes up and I have to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to continue. I would like to write a script to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> for me. I found an AutoIt script that seems to work once but I don't know how to loop it. I tried:

```
$i = 0
While $i <= WinActivate
    WinActive("Text Export Options") 
    Send("{ENTER}") 
    $i += 1
WEnd
```

But it crashed my computer. This is what works once:

```
WinWaitActive("Text Export Options")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
While True
    If WinActive("Text Export Options") then Send("{ENTER}")
Wend
```

Then just right-click the autoit tray icon and click exit once it is done.